# R - Error some group is too small for 'qda'

Tags: r, aero-glass

I'm trying to solve this problem from few days but google can't help :( 
I got Error like that:

> Error in qda.default(x, grouping, ...) :    some group is too small
>   for 'qda'

At stack were simillar topic:
[R Error : some group is too small for 'qda'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481772/r-error-some-group-is-too-small-for-qda)

But I cant find out how to do that : /

This is my code:

```
library(MASS)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(class)
data(Glass)
Glass <- data.frame(Glass)
Glass <- na.omit(Glass)

Glass$Type = as.factor(Glass$Type)
x = as.matrix(Glass[,names(Glass) != "Type"])
mode(x) = "numeric"
Glass[,names(Glass) != "Type"] <-x
ind <- sample(2, nrow(Glass), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
train <- Glass[ind == 1,]
test <- Glass[ind == 2,]
train[,names(Glass) != "Type"] <- apply(train[,names(Glass) != "Type"], 2, jitter)
```

Everything is great but next lines..

```
qda_Typeifier <- qda(Type~ ., data=train)
ypred.test <- predict(qda_Typeifier,test)$Type
mean(ypred.test == test$Type)
```

Hope, help will came soon!

Comment: did you checked this thread?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481772/r-error-some-group-is-too-small-for-qda?lq=1

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's not wrong code (there is little mistake), when this error show

> some group is too small for 'qda'

Tt means that the dataSet is wrong.
To repair that you should modify dataSet.